# Bootstrap 3 Panels with images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to re-create this panel:

[image]

I just wondered if anyone knows how I can go about this , I have my html markup done. But I have no idea how I would begin to style it..

My example html:

```
    <div id="mainContainer" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Item 01</div>
                <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give a custom class like `class_name` and than start

Comment: for the desired output don't use `panel-head` use `panel-body`

Comment: This question seems to be about styling rather than an actual *problem* ...what have you attempted and why didn't it work?

Comment: Im just not sure where to start on the styling at all, never used these panels before...

Comment: do you know there is css for styling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out this will help you....

```css
.my_panel > .panel-body {
  padding: 0px;
}
.my_panel > .panel-body > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.my_panel > .panel-footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="mainContainer" class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default my_panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <h3>The company</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, voluptas, sunt vitae mollitia iure perferendis rerum odio! Natus, cupiditate, est, quas, non perspiciatis in quo possimus eos voluptas tempore maxime.</p>
              <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```